# Наиболее подходящее совпадение

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть массив заранее подготовленных фраз, когда пользователь вводит что-то в `input` запускается обработчик `keyup`, который ищет в исходном массиве совпадения. Есть 2 фразы `Привет` и `Приветствую` массив перебираю циклом `for(key in data)`, затем ищу совпадение пользовательского ввода в ячейках массива

```
inputVal = $.trim($(this).val()); // значение в инпуте
data[key].answer.indexOf(inputVal) != -1 // если нашел совпадение в массиве - вывожу его
```

НО сейчас выводится просто первое попавшееся совпадение, например если ввести `привет` , то как результат работы условия возвращается `приветствую`.
Как можно искать самое точное совпадение?) что-бы если ввели `привет` и такой ответ есть в массиве , то именно его я и получил в результате работы цикла/условия. Заранее спасибо!

P.S. фраз в массиве может быть рандомное число. При этом введенная фраза может браться не целая т.к. обработчик стоит на нажатие клавиши, например значение в инпуте может быть просто `п` или `при` или что угодно)

Comment: Подозреваю, что answer у вас строка, а не массив

Comment: `.answer === inputVal` должно помочь

Comment: да, массив, точнее объект у меня data в котором много полей, я из него беру только одно нужно поле с ответом data[key].answer

Comment: Действительно, спасибо большое, работает) для более удобного поиска, например по процентному соотношению введенного слова от слова в массиве, наверное легче всего юзать какую-то библиотеку, у jquery IU вроде есть подобная...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно выбирать наименьший из содержащих подстроку:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input');
const map = {
  f1: {answer: 'Привет'},
  f2: {answer: 'Приветствую'}
}

input.addEventListener('keyup', ev => {
  const el = ev.target;
  const val = el.value;
  if (!val) return true;
  const variants = Object.keys(map)
    .map(k => map[k].answer) // получаем все ответы
    .filter(v => v.indexOf(val) !== -1) // Выбираем только подходящие
    .sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length); // сортируем по длине
  if (variants.length && el.value !== variants[0]) {
    el.value = variants[0]; // выбираем наименьший, если есть
  }
});
```

```html
<input id=input>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно найти только элемент в точности равный строке, то можно сравнивать значения на точное соответствие оператором == Вот так:

```js
const p = [
  {
    id: 1,
    data: 'приветик',
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    data: 'привет',
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    data: 'приветствую',
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    data: 'приветочек',
  },
];

console.log(p.find(e=>e.data === 'привет'));
```

если искать надо все, что начинается с чего-то, то можно использовать регулярное выражения для сравнения начала строк. Вот так:

```js
const p = [
  {
    id: 1,
    data: 'приветик',
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    data: 'привет',
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    data: 'приветиком',
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    data: 'приветствую',
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    data: 'приветочек',
  },
];

console.log(p.reduce((p,c)=>{
  if(c.data.search(/^привети/) !== -1){
    p.push(c);
  }
  
  return p;
}, []));
```